# Filling dictionary for mix of int and str

Tags: python

I want to populate dict in the following format:

```
columns=[14,116]
spaces = {'A':[int(i) for i in range(0,columns[0])], 'B': [int(i) for i in range(0,columns[1])]}
```

That's easy if cols only [14,116], but I will get problem if cols have, for example here I have cols=[14,16,117,18,180,190]. To solve this, I tried this code:

```
alphabet=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
columns=[14,16,117,18,180,190]
spaces = dict(zip(alphabet, [int(i) for i in range(0,columns)]))
```

But I don't have an idea of putting columns[0],columns[1] inside zip

The expected output:

```
namespaces = {'A':[int(i) for i in range(0,cols[0])],
                   'B': [int(i) for i in range(0,cols[1])], 'C': [int(i) for i in range(0,cols[2])], and so on...}
```

BTW, The above error throws an error:

`range()` integer end argument expected, got list.

Comment: You know that `int(i) for i in range` is simply `range`, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
alphabet=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
cols=[14,16,117,18,180,190]
new_dict = dict(zip(alphabet, cols))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 14, 'C': 117, 'B': 16, 'E': 180, 'D': 18, 'F': 190}
```

Edit: using the `range` function:

```
new_dict = {a:list(range(b)) for a, b in zip(alphabet, cols)}
```

Comment: Hi. I have edited the question. I posted the wrong version question. So sorry!

Comment: Thanks but The expected output should look something like: namespaces = {'A':[int(i) for i in range(0,cols[0])], 'B': [int(i) for i in range(0,cols[1])], 'C': [int(i) for i in range(0,cols[2])], and so on...}

Comment: superb! Thank you